# How to Move a mc while the other mc moves in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I Have a Mc named as thumb. And i have other mc named as track. When i move the thumb_mc using my script below, i also need my track_mc to move.

```
thumb.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, thumb_onMouseDown);
function thumb_onMouseDown(event:MouseEvent):void {
xOffset = mouseX - thumb.x;
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, stage_onMouseMove);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stage_onMouseUp);
}

function stage_onMouseMove(event:MouseEvent):void {
thumb.x = mouseX - xOffset;
//restrict the movement of the thumb:
if(thumb.x < 8) {
    thumb.x = 8;
}
if(thumb.x > 540) {
    thumb.x = 540;
}

event.updateAfterEvent();
}
function stage_onMouseUp(event:MouseEvent):void {
stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, stage_onMouseMove);
stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stage_onMouseUp);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple, just add one line of code to set the track.x value to the thumb.x inside the stage_onMouseMove function.

One important thing to note is to add it at the end of the function so that it received the value after it is updated with the bounding check, like this:

```
function stage_onMouseMove(event:MouseEvent):void {
thumb.x = mouseX - xOffset;
//restrict the movement of the thumb:
    if(thumb.x < 8) {
        thumb.x = 8;
    }
    if(thumb.x > 540) {
        thumb.x = 540;
    }

    track.x = thumb.x; // move track with the thumb
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your mouse_move a bit:

```
function stage_onMouseMove(event:MouseEvent):void {
   thumb.x = mouseX - xOffset;
   // move your track also
   track.x = mouseX - someXOffset;
   track.y = mouseY - someYOffset;
   ...
}
```

Or if you need to move track ONLY when thumb is moving you can do following:

Add variable to store previous thumb position `var previousPos:int`;

In mouse_down add such code `previousPos = thumb.x`;

And then modify mouse move in such way:

```
function stage_onMouseMove(event:MouseEvent):void {
    thumb.x = mouseX - xOffset;
    //restrict the movement of the thumb:
    if(thumb.x < 8) {
       thumb.x = 8;
    }
    if(thumb.x > 540) {
       thumb.x = 540;
    }
    if(previousPos != thumb.x){
        //moving track here
        track.x = somevalue;
    }
    previousPos = track.x;
    ...
}
```

Comment: i don have any y values here for my code. . I just need the things move from right to left and from left to right like a scroll bar kinda thing . And i need both to move in one click with the mouse

Comment: Anyway I updated my answer a bit, please check if it helps you